# How do I install rJava properly on MX Linux

Tags: r, linux, rjava

I am trying to install `rJava`, as it's a dependency of `OpenStreetMap` (I want to create some maps).

However, when trying to install, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre2-8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmplfpzAZ/R.INSTALL2958202af052/rJava/jri/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile.all:35: libjri.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmplfpzAZ/R.INSTALL2958202af052/rJava/jri'
make[1]: *** [Makefile.all:19: src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [Makevars:14: jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/maanan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpRkgFko/downloaded_packages’
```

Could someone please tell me what I did wrong? I have JDK and JRE installed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered installing the package it bemoans?  `apt install   libpcre2-8-0 libpcre2-dev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt install   libpcre2-8-0 libpcre2-dev
```

That will (should) get you past the error at the very top. Of course I don't know what else you might be missing.  Please google future  errors you may get ...

Comment: Thank you. I have googled the problem, but I could not find this solution.